# Can we override Drupal includes files?

Tags: 6

I want to modify the menu.inc file that is in the Drupal "includes" folder, but I want to create an overriding file for it, so that we can easily package only our custom theme.

Comment: There's no in-built mechanism to override a whole system file, no. Drupal has a hook system that allows you to alter pretty much anything...what exactly do you need to change?

Answer (score 3):

Generally Clive is right. Don't touch core. But sometimes you are forced to do a core patch or it's just much easier to solve your requirements.

If you must: I'd recommend to put your whole project into git. This gives you the possibility to have a clean core version in one branch and the patched one in an other. Everytime a new core version is published you can merge it in a clean way.